# Can we execute test scripts in msedge browser on ubuntu 20.4 using Karate framework?

Tags: karate, ui-automation

I wanted to execute my UI automation test scripts in msedge browser on ubuntu 20.4.

Tried with below two approach:

1. Installed msedge, and tried execution by providing executable path of browser.
2. Downloaded msedgedriver and provided executable path for the same.

However, not able to execute and getting error as  "driver config / start failed: start failed"

Is it possible to execute scripts in msedge browser on ubuntu 20.4?

Comment: I don't know for sure. non-typical combinations may need more testing and community feedback + contribution. please consider contributing to the code if possible, or maybe you should look into using a cloud environment like lambdatest etc.